# Recursive Query on Single Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which follows the following structure;

```
Tablename: Codes
ID int
CodeID int
ParentID int
Name varchar
```

Is it possibly in MSSQL 2012 to perform a query in CTE to select all values recursively?

If CodeID = NULL than this is the root of codes. When you go down a step the ParentID will relate to the CodeID.

e.g SELECT Name FROM Codes Where ID = null AND ParentID = X

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean to select all values recursively?  The following selects all values:

```
select *
from codes;
```

Let me assume that you want all ancestors for all codes in the hierarchy.  You can do that with a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select c.id, c.codeid, c.parentid, c.name,
             cast(c.id as varchar(255)) as ids
      from Codes c
      union all
      select cte.id, cte.codeid, c.parentid, cte.name,
             cast(cte.ids +','+cast(c.parentid as varchar(255)) as varchar(255))
      from cte join
           Codes c
           on cte.parentid = c.id and c.parentid is not null and
              ','+cast(cte.parentid as varchar(255))+',' not like '%,'+ids+'%,'
    )
select *
from cte;
```

You can this filter this for a particular parent id to get all nodes beneath it.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/13160) is a SQL Fiddle showing a working version.